# Suggestion for eager loading associations with dynamic conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**Rails 3.1.** Currently I have an association that has dynamic conditions that depends on the country/locale.

```
class Article
  has_many :comments, :conditions => Proc.new { { :country => Comment.country } } 
end

Comment.country = "US"

# Eager loads comments from the US
Article.includes(:comments).all
```

As you can see, I am setting a class attribute flag `Comment.country` to tell `Article` the country to articles need to be for when eager-loading them. It works but I am worried about race conditions since something like `Comment.country` would be shared across all user sessions. Can someone please recommend me a better way to do this?

**Update**:
To be more specific, I want to eager load my association to keep my SQL queries at a minimum. Furthermore, when doing something like

```
@article.comments
```

it will pull in the comments that have been eager loaded based on the conditions. I don't want to do something like

```
@article.comments.where(:country => "US")
```

because not only is it more SQL queries, calling `@article.comments` will *not* be referring to the same collection of comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think relationally, what do you want your sql to look like? Are you just trying to reduce the number of queries to load the country code?

Also, remember that lazy loading can sometimes be just as fast as loading eagerly depending on how much data is coming back from the database.